# Cross-Compiling a GLUT project for Windows on Linux with static linking

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, cross-compiling, glut

I am trying to cross-compile this minimal GLUT Program:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Cross-compile testing");
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

The commands I use:

- Compile on Linux:   g++ main.cpp -lglut -o main
- Cross-Compile Dynamic: `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -lglut -o main.exe`
- Cross-Compile Static:  `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -static -DFREEGLUT_STATIC -lglut -o main.exe`

- Compiling on Archlinux (64bit, 1st command above) works fine
- Compiling for Windows (32bit, 2nd command above) with dynamic linking works fine
- Compiling for Windows (32bit, 3rd command above) with static linking gives me some undefined reference errors:

```
/tmp/ccIXyF1j.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'
/tmp/ccIXyF1j.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit' 
/tmp/ccIXyF1j.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit' 
/tmp/ccIXyF1j.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode' 
/tmp/ccIXyF1j.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
```

Any ideas on that? I am using the MinGW freeglut package from the Archlinux AUR (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mingw-w64-freeglut/).
Adding `-mwindows` to the compiler options or `#include <windows.h>` to the code doesn't help either.

In my cross-compiler's lib folder I have

```
./libglut32.a
./libglut.la
./libglut.a
./libglut.dll.a
```

What am I doing wrong?
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You are not linking to the static link library. Judging by your file organization, I would hazard a guess that `-lglut32` is necessary when you define `FREEGLUT_STATIC`.

Comment: Adding `-lglut32` unfortunately doesn't change anything at all... But still thanks for your reply.